# How do I select distinct values in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.6

This is my code:

```
[app.system_name for app in App.objects.all().distinct('system_name')]
```

Gives me:

```
[u'blog', u'files', u'calendar', u'tasks', u'statuses', u'wiki', u'wiki', u'blog
', u'files', u'blog', u'ideas', u'calendar', u'wiki', u'wiki', u'statuses', u'ta
sks', u'survey', u'blog']
```

As you might expect I want all the unique values of the field system_name, but now I just get all App instances back.

Comment: You can always throw the values in a `set` to remove duplicates _ex post facto_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Specifying fields in `distinct` is only supported in Django 1.4+. If you're running 1.3,   it's just ignoring it.
2. If you *are* running Django 1.4, you must add an `order_by` clause that includes and starts with all the fields in `distinct`.
3. Even then, specifying fields with `distinct` is only support on PostgreSQL. If you're running something else, such as MySQL, you're out of luck.

All this information is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

Comment: Hmm I guess I'm out of luck then since we're using 1.3.

Comment: As far as doing it this way, yes, you seem to be out of luck. But, this is a classic case of asking about a why a certain method doesn't work, instead of simply asking how to do the actual thing you want. You should create a new question concerning how to remove duplicate values in your queryset, or simply search SO for such a question. I know I'm seen similar ones before.

Answer (score 10):

You have to [order by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) the same field name when using [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) with a field name:

```
App.objects.order_by('system_name').distinct('system_name')
```

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the
>   QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in
>   distinct(), in the same order.
>
> For example, SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) gives you the first row for each
>   value in column a. If you don't specify an order, you'll get some
>   arbitrary row.

Comment: mysql does not support using distinct() with a parameter though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use values_list() when using distinct().

```
App.objects.values_list('system_name').distinct()
```