# sqlite3 error when updating to django 1.4

Tags: django, sqlite, django-1.4

I have created a new virtual environment so that I can update my code from django1.3 to django1.4.  The django1.3 environment has no issues with the sqlite version and database I am using.  The Django1.4 version gives me a error of:

```
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

I am not finding any information on changes to the new version that might cause this.  Does anyone know why it might work fine in 1.3 and not 1.4?

Comment: some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518947/select-distinct-in-django how it worked in 1.3 for you seems hard to say without seeing your code